# How to stop only pods that meet certain conditions in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have an application inside a pod where users should be connected all the time until they themselves disconnect from it. Given that these pods should only be stopped by Kubernetes when certain criteria are met, otherwise the active connection will be disrupted when something like rescaling happens as Kubernetes isn't aware that there are active connections. In this case the "user_connected_count" (provided by metrics) should be 0.

Is there any way in Kubernetes to only stop pods that match a specific condition? Do I need to implement something by myself?

Comment: you could try to use pre-stop hook, https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/

Comment: You've probably heard about **cattle versus pets** metaphor according to which kubernetes pods are considered a cattle, not pets. A pod can be killed and recreated for a thousend of reasons so you cannot really rely on it when running something that cannot be interrupted and then resumed at a later time. Take a look at [Pod Disruptions and Pod disruption budgets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/) but it won't guarantee you that a particular pod won't be disrupted, so I would say you should rather find some way to resolve it on the application side.

Comment: Thanks for your help @mario. You are right about fixing the problem at application level. However I only have control over the server and not the client code and logic. Otherwise I would have fixed it at application level.

Answer (score 0):

*posting my comment as an answer for better visibility*

You've probably heard about **cattle versus pets** metaphor according to which kubernetes pods are considered a cattle, not pets. A pod can be killed and recreated for a thousand of reasons so you cannot really rely on it when running something that cannot be interrupted and then resumed at a later time. Take a look at [Pod Disruptions and Pod disruption budgets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/) but it won't guarantee you that a particular pod won't be disrupted, so I would say you should rather find some way to resolve it on the application side.